# C# Interrupt stream deserialization

Tags: c#, multithreading, serialization, deserialization

I have a thread running that continuously listens on a stream for messages (of type `Message` and its subtypes) and sorts them into the appropriate bins (e.g. `Response` type messages go into one bin, `Info` type messages go in another, etc.), so other threads may check and/or retrieve messages from whichever bin they're interested in. The problem is that I don't know how to interrupt it. `Interrupt()`ing the thread doesn't cause a `ThreadInterruptedException` to be thrown in its run loop for some reason. Even `Dispose()`ing the stream doesn't stop it from waiting, which is strange.

The thread's run loop resembles the following:

```
protected virtual void Run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            Message m = Receive();
            MessageBins[GetMessageType(m)].TryAdd(m);
        }
    } catch (ThreadInterruptedException) {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("Interrupted!"); // DEBUG, never reaches here, even when interrupted
    } catch (SerializationException e) {
        // ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

where `Receive()` looks something like

```
public TMessage Receive<TMessage>() where TMessage : Message {
    return (TMessage) Formatter.Deserialize(Stream);
}
```

How does one interrupt this?

Comment: is there any reason to use the thread ?  why not TPL?

Comment: Having tried and failed to solve similar problems before on Windows, I can sympathise. I never found a satisfactory solution. You could poll the stream to see if there's anything to read, that would allow you to also check a cancellation token or something. As @BRAHIM Kamel suggested, Task Parallel Library may be of assistance.

Comment: Just for the sake of discussion (apologies - hijacking), it's easy to do this kind of thing on *nix - `select()` and it's applicability to file descriptors of all sorts is very useful for Actor Model programming. Traditionally it's been difficult to create an equivalent for Windows without resorting to polling (which is what Cygwin did). However, now that Win 10 has a Linux kernal interface, one wonders how MS have supported `select()` for file descriptors of all sorts. I got the distinct impression in the past that it was fundamentlly not supported by the NT kernel. I wonder what's changed?

Comment: `Thread.Interrupt` doesn't immediately throw an exception in the interrupted thread, it only throws it when the thread would next begin to block.  If `Formatter.Deserialize` is blocked waiting to read from the stream, then the exception can never get thrown, since it would have to stop blocking first.  The [documentation for `Thread.Interrupt` mentions this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.interrupt(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Monad Rose just note that using thread is considered as a bad practice